# Why does referencing a jQuery selector in one property of an object, from another property of the same object throw an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I log the top property here I get an object, but the property declaration for property 2 throws an error saying the property is undefined. Why is this? How can I store these selectors at the top of an object so that I can use in that object's methods?

```
objectName = {
        property: $('#element'),
        property2: this.property.children('.filter-class'),

        myFunction: function() {
            var property2 = this.property2;

            property2.on('click', function() {
                property2.addClass(className);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because the `this` -value is scoped to functions, not objects

Comment: The first `this` references whatever `this` is outside of that object. it isn't what you are thinking it is

Comment: And you can't reference a property of an object before that object has finished being constructed either.

Comment: In that case, is it impossible to reference the value of property from property2?

Comment: The way you're doing it, yes, it's impossible. You could make it a function instead though, but there doesn't seem to be much point, just get the children inside `myFunction`, or use `$('#element').children()` for `property2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed out it should be:

```
objectName = {
    property: $('#element'),
    property2: $('#element').children('.filter-class'),

    myFunction: function() {
        var property2 = this.property2;

        property2.on('click', function() {
            property2.addClass(className);
        });
    }
}
```

when you declare property2 `this` refers to window object not `objectName`